# Galloping incompetence & galloping ineptitude

Tags: meaning

Is it correct to use "galloping" as a synonym of "extreme"? For example, I often see "galloping incompetence" and "galloping ineptitude".

But Merriam Webster's only definition is "progressing, developing, or increasing rapidly". I doubt that is what is meant by "galloping incompetence" and "galloping ineptitude". However it seems like a very useful and colorful way to use the word as it suggests moving rapidly toward the *consequences* of extreme incompetence or ineptitude.

Comment: Often? Google Ngrams finds no results for either.

Comment: Might be a malapropism for _galling_...

Comment: @KateBunting I wasn't familiar with Google Ngrams so I googled it, and found: "Is Google's Ngram Viewer Accurate? Before we leave you, we should raise a note of caution: Google's Ngram Viewer is a useful tool, but it isn't perfect! It only looks at published books, with an emphasis on scientific literature, so its results won't perfectly reflect how people use words in the real world." Meanwhile, Google finds 392 results for "galloping incompetence" and 47 for "galloping ineptitude".

Comment: ...I don't think we should be surprised that such a creatively hyperbolic term isn't found in published scientific literature books.

Comment: @KateBunting Interesting that ngrams turns up nothing, because a Google Books search (with quote marks) turns up plenty!

Comment: Meanwhile, there are plenty of dictionary entries noting that "galloping" can be used metaphorically to mean "progressing rapidly," e.g. "galloping inflation." But I don't know that this usage is necessarily implying progression. I think it's just there as a vigorous intensifier. It's bugging me because I've definitely heard the usage but can't dig up a dictionary that will corroborate it as official.

Comment: @GregLovern That's a very small number. I agree that this is likely the result of confusion with the much more common *galling.*

Comment: @alphabet I've read through a few of the hits from googling "galloping incompetence". I really doubt most of the writers are failing to distinguish between galloping and galling. That said, I don't get the impression they're really thinking through the meaning to the level we're discussing here. Rather, I get the impression that maybe they just like to write it. One of them put "galloping" in front of several different derogetory words.

Comment: *Galloping* is not interchangeable with *extreme*, but one could imagine some circumstances in which *galloping incompetence* would be an apt metaphor. Suppose, for example, that some incompetent, but fast talking and very assertive people drown the voices of the competent ones in some decision-making process. Couldn't that be metaphorically described as a case of galloping incompetence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Galloping* means *runaway* or ***out of control*** here. You can find it used in that sense in business dictionaries under *galloping inflation*. From *Longman Business English Dictionary* via [LDOCE Online](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/galloping-inflation):

> **galloping inflation** (also **runaway inflation**)
>  very high inflation that is out of control SYN HYPERINFLATION
> *the galloping inflation of the late 1980s*
> *a plan to rid Brazil of its runaway inflation, which exceeded 4,800% in the preceding 12 months*

Although the *OED*’s defintion (*That gallops, in senses of the verb **galloping consumption** noun a consumptive disease which makes rapid progress*) is unsatisfying, its usage samples under ***figurative*** display the runaway sense (and clearly don’t mean *progressing rapidly*):

> <sub>1755   No galloping eyes, or the least inattention in their
> devotion.</sub>
>  <sub>1770   What a blessing it is to have a
> galloping imagination.</sub>
>  <sub>1896   Ever since they had
> taken him he had been oppressed by this plague of galloping
> thought.</sub>
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

For a horse theme, compare *unbridled*, as in *unbridled enthusiasm*:

> **unbridled** *adjective*
> **1.** *figurative*. Not restrained or held in check; absolutely uncontrolled or ungoverned...
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Comment: Similarly [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/galloping) has "progressing at or as if at a gallop: *galloping consumption*" with "run somewhere very quickly" and "see [at a gallop](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-a-gallop)" (=very quickly) among the definitions of "gallop".